# Appcelerator Alloy Android -Cannot add window/tabGroup to another window/tabGroup

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have an app which works in IOS 6. I am trying to get it to work on basically any andriod version. 
I have an index controller and view which load fine.

I can load the register page but when I bypass the register page. It works fine in IOS but not Android. I am not using tabgroups just windows.

Any ideas ? *NOTE I can't get the full xml tags to load in code view which is why there are no brackets.*

I get this error:

> new Error("Cannot add window/tabGroup to another window/tabGroup.");

**Index Controller**

```
    if (!isRegistered) {
        var register = Alloy.createController( 'register' );
        register.getView().open();
    }
    else {
        var main = Alloy.createController( 'main' );
        Alloy.Globals.mainController = main;
    }
```

**index view**

```
Alloy
    Window id="index"

        Require type="view" src="slider" id="slider"
    Window

Alloy
```

**main js controller**

```
// code above
$.main.open();
// code below
```

**main view**

```
Alloy
    Window id="index"

        View id="loadingOverlay" /

        View id="main"

            ImageView id="background" image="/images/background.jpg"/

            Require type="view" src="slider" id="slider" /

            /OptionDialog

        /View
    /Window
/Alloy
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

the error messag explains it

**new Error("Cannot add window/tabGroup to another window/tabGroup.");**

hard to tell what is going on here, you might need to add a gist or pastebin, but a window cannot contain another window